# Issues with UITableViewCell contenView width on iPad

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

I've a UITableViewCell with custom headerView, footerView and ContentView. On iPhone (devices & simulator) renders fine, and the width of contentView adjust to the cell perfectly. But on iPad (booth device / simulator) the contentView is smaller than the UITableViewCell and shows a left and right margins. HeaderView and footerView adjust right to screen and UITableViewCell, only the contentView has this issue,

how can I resize the contentView to adjust equal than header and footer view? I've tried with autoresizing mask for flexible width without any result...

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the frame of the `contentView` to the width of the `UITableViewCell` manually?

```
contentView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, cell.frame.size.width, contentView.frame.size.height);
```